# Hibernate session threadsafe in SLSB?

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, java-ee-6

Does managing hibernate Session in a stateless EJB 3.1 (BeanManagedTransaction) makes the session threadsafe in Java EE 6 environment?

If so, then how to manage concurrent access so that each thread runs parallely.

Comment: Show us the code you use in your SLSB

Answer (score 2):

No. I can't imagine how that should work.

The session object is not threadsafe neither the objects returned by the session instance are. For example if two threads use one session instance to select entities, and both select the same database entity, then the one session instance makes the same instance of the entity pojo available to both threads. The concurrent access to this single pojo instance will fail.

Different threads definitively need different Session instances.